# Check if array is null and has content

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I'm in search for some code-improvement. I currently have the following piece of code:

```
        if (pMyDocAction.s_locatie_st != null)
        {
            String[] myLocaties = Globals.GlobalTools.DeserializeValueToStringArray(pMyDocAction.s_locatie_st);
            if (myLocaties != null)
                if (myLocaties.Length > 0)
                    row.Locatie = myLocaties[0];
                else
                    row.Locatie = String.Empty;
            else
                row.Locatie = String.Empty;
        }
        else
            row.Locatie = String.Empty;
```

`Mylocaties` is a `Array of String` and this cannot change. How can i shorten this piece of code (or how can i combine the `!= null` and `.length > 0`?

Thnx

Comment: Thnx everyone for the quick answers! If learned lots of new ways to tackle the mentionned problem. +1 to everyone! I will give the credits to selman though as he was to quickest poster and i'm using a variant of his code. Also a great thnx to CodeCaster for pointing out that this code might be better suited in my Globals class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *conditional* operator and write that statement like this:

```
row.Locatie =  (myLocaties != null && 
                myLocaties.Length > 0) ? myLocaties[0] : String.Empty
```

Comment: The null-coalescing operator is `??`, not `?`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a small extension method:

```
public static class ArrayExtension{
    public static bool HasContent<T>(Array<T> array) {
         return array != null && array.Length > 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can check :

```
int[] x = null;

x.HasContent(); // false

string[] strs = new string[] {};

strs.HasContent(); // false

string[] strs2 = new string[] {"foo", "bar" };

strs.HasContent(); // true
```

This can be extended to simplify your syntax:

```
public static class ArrayExtension{
    public static T FirstValueOrDefault<T>(Array<T> array, T @default) {
         if( array != null && array.Length >0 ){
              return array[0];
         }
         else {
              return @default;
         }
    }
}


int[] x = null;

int y = x.FirstValueOrDefault(42); // 42

string[] strs = new string[] {};

string some = strs.FirstValueOrDefault("default"); // default

string[] strs2 = new string[] {"foo", "bar" };

 string some2 = strs.FirstValueOrDefault("default"); // foo
```

Comment: I like this semantic.  I would name it a little different, but nothing comes to mind right away  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) on two conditions, it will do [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and if first condition is false, it will not evaluate the second condition.

```
if (myLocaties != null && myLocaties.Length > 0)
{
    row.Locatie = myLocaties[0];
}
else
{
   row.Locatie = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all other answers seem to ignore the `if (pMyDocAction.s_locatie_st != null)`, something like this seems to be the most reusable:

```
row.Locatie = DeserializeLocation(pMyDocAction.s_locatie_st);

string DeserializeLocation(string locationString)
{
    var result = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationString))
    {
        String[] deserializedLocations = 
            Globals.GlobalTools.DeserializeValueToStringArray(locationString);

        if (deserializedLocations != null && deserializedLocations.Any())
        {
            result = deserializedLocations[0];
        }
    }   

    return result;
}
```

You might even consider putting this method in your "`GlobalTools`" class, so you can call it from anywhere were you need to deserialize a potentially null-bearing serialized location string into a location string.